# $_POST empty in using new php file added to theme

Tags: jquery, ajax, hooks, forms, rewrite-rules

I am using a theme which handles form data with jquery (a handler function defined).I have added a new php file to theme (using it in as template  in a wordpress page,  also registered with rewrite rules).

*The Problem is when I submit form, handler function receives no data ($_POST empty). 
   Also Firefox popus up a message "To display this page, Firefox Developer Edition must send information that will repeat any action".
This message pops up because javascript tryies to reload page using this function :"jQuery.post(form.attr('action'), data, function(response) "
In other template files which forms works correctly,this function doesnt execute.

I have checked jquery handler and it seems it submits form correctly.I dont know what problem is.

Other template forms have no problems.

Does wordpress core cant send data from jquery to handler function?

Sorry for my poor english. 
Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by somebody:

“if my form pointed to a directory:

http://example.com/wordpress

then my POST data disappeared and $_POST was empty. If I pointed to a specific file:
http://example.com/wordpress/index.php

Then it worked properly."

ps: God bless him. :)